# Web video from archive.org does not play

Tags: video

I have an Android 9 box with Chrome and Firefox installed. Usually if video does not play in one browser, it does play in another, YouTube works in both. However, videos from archive.org do not play, one can select an episode, but when one clicks on white triangle to play nothing happens. I can play on laptop, there if I Ctrl+click on the video, it says JW Player 8.8.2. I am new to Android; how do I fix/troubleshoot?

Example link: https://archive.org/details/poirot-series/01.06+Triangle+At+Rhodes.mkv

Comment: I have downloaded this video from archive.org with Chrome. Chrome downloads files to some hidden folder, but when download is complete, it appears in Files and in Chrome downloads. It does not play in Chrome when downloaded. It can be opened in 4 video players from Files: TVMC Player (version of Kodi) cannot see the file, VLC can play, Movie player and Video player (I guess these are built in Files or system, as they have no icons in launcher) one can and one cannot show video.